# Smooth fibers in Stein factorization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be projective varieties over the complex numbers with $X$ smooth. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a projective surjective morphism with connected fibers. Let $\tilde f : X \to \tilde Y, g : \tilde Y \to Y, f= g \circ \tilde f$ be the Stein factorization. Then $g$ is bijective [Debarre, Higher dimensional Algebraic geometry, 1.13]. If all scheme-theoretic fibers of $f$ are smooth and irreducible (not necessarily of the same dimension), is $g$ an isomorphism?

Comment: No, $g$ can send $\mathbb P^1$ to a cuspidal curve.

Comment: sorry, I meant "scheme-theoretic" fibers (I have modified the question). In the case $\mathbb P^1$ to a cuspidal curve, I believe there is a non-reduced scheme-theoretic fiber

Comment: Then the answer should be yes: If all scheme-theoretic fibers of $f$ are reduced, then so is $g$. As $g$ is bijective, this implies that $g$ induces isomorphism on the local ring at each closed point, therefore is an isomorphism.

Comment: it is not clear to me that all fibers of $g$ must be reduced. My idea was similar: we have that the differential of $f$ is injective, but how does this imply that the same holds for $g$? It would be OK if the differential of $\tilde f$ is surjective (is it?)

Comment: I think you want the condition of the differential of $f$ is being surjective, instead of being injective.

Comment: I did not write well. My idea was to prove that $dg$ is injective using that $d{\tilde f}_x$ is surjective (?) and the fact that $df_x(v) \ne 0$ if $v \in T_xX$ and $v$ is not tangent to the fiber of $f$ at $x$. In any case: how to prove that $dg$ is injective or surjective?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133959/discussion-between-cob-and-ag-learner).